# Проблемы с кодировкой CP866

Tags: c#, кодировка

Есть файл (пример [тут](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B54pmI7siNu5Q2o3RzRwTXVnbjQ/view?usp=sharing), 10 байт), открываю его в TotalCommander по F3 и вижу

> Р°ТђВ¬В®В­

Открываю в Блокноте (по F4) и вижу

> аҐ¬®­

Эта строка в кодировке CP866.
Декодирую ей и получаю "ремон" - то, что и ожидал.

**Проблемы**:

1. На другом компе это же файл по F3 открывается как

> Р°ТђВ¬В®В­

но и по F4 в блокноте открывается также. Нужно понять почему и чего не хватает второму компу, чтобы открывать файл в блокноте также как на первом. Если на обоих компах открыть файл в Firefox и выбрать кодировку Unicode, то в обоих случаях будет

> аҐ¬®­

2. Как на C# это

> Р°ТђВ¬В®В­

перекодировать в это

> аҐ¬®­

А лучше сразу в исходный "ремон".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На лицо неверное перекодирование между ANSI, ASCI и UTF-8.
Судя по длине строки исходный текст utf-8.
Всему вместо аҐ¬® явно предполагалось аҐ¬®- (последний символ непечатный \xAD — перенос) — 866 в отображении 1251.

Причина в сохранении искаженного представления 866to1251 = аҐ¬®- в формате utf-8.
Следовательно решение - utf-8=>1251=>866.

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте просто [`File.ReadAllText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143369%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) с нужной кодировкой:

```
var text = File.ReadAllText(filename, Encoding.GetEncoding(866));
```

Answer (score 2):

ЕМНИП, дело может быть в кодировке не поддерживающих Unicode приложений (см. где-то в панели управления).

В любом случае - можно :

1. прочитать как массив байт (File.ReadAllBytes)
2. преобразовать от CP866 к текущей дефолтовой кодировке (Encoding.Convert).
3. преобразовать в строку (Encoding.getString)

Answer (score 1):

Не хватает нужной кодировки. Какие ОС используются на компьютерах?
Вам нужно перекодировать файл (текст) в UTF-8 ну или CP1251.
Используйте функцию Encoding.Convert(<Исходная кодировка>, <Нужная кодировка>, <массив байтов исходного файла>);

Answer (score 1):

1. Разница в "интуиции" Total Commander на разных компах может объясняться настройками программы. TC под рукой нет, но у его родного брата Far Manager есть соответствующий пункт в свойствах вьюера и редактора: автодетект и кодировака по умолчанию.
2. Перекодировать текст в другую кодировку на C# можно через класс Encoding:
   https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.text.encoding