# Считать файл в нужной кодировке

Tags: c#, кодировка

Всем доброго дня. Подскажите пожалуйста. Есть файл txt в кодировке ASCII. хочу считать с него данные и скопировать в новый файл в UTF8. В новый файл выводит кривой текст.
Подскажите как можно сделать и где ошибка.

```
string path = open.FileName;

string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path);



StreamReader read = new StreamReader(path,Encoding.ASCII);
               
string newFilePath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(path), $"{fileName}123.txt");

File.WriteAllText(newFilePath, read.ReadToEnd(),Encoding.UTF8);
```

Comment: А что у вас в исходном файле находится? Уверены что в ASCII кодировке? код выглядит правильным

Comment: Похоже Вы правы. Notepad показывает OEM 866. Тогда вопрос, как ее считать?) В Encoding не найду подобного.

Comment: Попробуйте Encoding.GetEncoding(866) вместо ASCII

Comment: Версия дотнета какая? А вообще ASCII полностьтна 100% совместима с UTF-8, то есть файл, записанный в ASCII, можно считать без каких-либо преобразований в UTF-8, но конечно же наоборот не получится. А вот 866 это уже другая история.

Comment: Похожая проблема была тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/414326/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D1%81-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-cp866

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил так:
Установил пакет System.Text.Encoding.CodePages
В Main добавил Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);

Comment: Пакет для этого устанавливать не нужно